# using a batch file to add a carriage return when a character is found

Tags: batch-file

I have a file that I want it to search through, find a tilde(~) and add a carriage return after.

```
FINDSTR /I /R "~" *.txt > *.new
ECHO ^ >> *.new
DEL *.txt
REN *.new *.txt
```

This is what I have tried, as I have a group of files that I want to convert, but when I run the bat file nothing seems to happen.

Edit:

the files look like this:

```
~*n1* first name last name * numbers*~r1* data*~**strong text**
```

Comment: Not sure if I am following your description or example. Could you add an example of your input file and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: you are actually writing the output of search result to a file name *.new , which is in correct , and you are not searching single file for occurrence of  "~" instead your searching all text files in that directory.

Comment: The input file is a long string of characters that is broken up with tildes. usually I can go in and do a find and replace; where I replace the ~ with a ~\n.  
  
the files look like this:  

~*n1* first name last name * numbers*~r1* data*~  
  
  
I normally have a lot of files that I have to do this to, so that is why I have the *.* in the above. I was originally trying to do this with just one file to see if I could get it working.

Comment: @Tom, you can edit your original question to include the input and output examples.

Comment: Sounds like completely the wrong tool for the job. Look at PowerShell (or sed, or awk).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler  I did, I don't have permissions to run PowerShell scripts from my PC (But I have it installed on my PC....).

Comment: @Tom "you don't have permissions" meaning you can't run PowerShell at all, or meaning you get the ExecutionPolicy block? Because the latter isn't really a block, it's more of a safety guard, and can be easily changed with `Set-ExecutionPolicy`, e.g. `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process`